# Visual studio 2015 project templates are not showing up

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I just installed Visual Studio 2015, after installing Azure SDK I am seeing very limited project templates.

[image]

I have selected Web Development tools while installing VS2015

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was using visual studio blend, which is not a full version. Closing this.